# I am using Vaadin 23 and Spring security with PostgresSQL. I have entity, repository and service classes are done. need help - login authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security, vaadin, basic-authentication, vaadin23

I want to modify the bean public UserDetailsManager userDetailsService(). I want to get the username from the login form and find if the user exist in the database and then return the usedaetails using that found user.
here is the code given by vaadin docs. I dont want to use InMemoryUserDetailsManager.

```
@EnableWebSecurity 
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration
                extends VaadinWebSecurity { 

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Delegating the responsibility of general configurations
        // of http security to the super class. It's configuring
        // the followings: Vaadin's CSRF protection by ignoring
        // framework's internal requests, default request cache,
        // ignoring public views annotated with @AnonymousAllowed,
        // restricting access to other views/endpoints, and enabling
        // ViewAccessChecker authorization.
        // You can add any possible extra configurations of your own
        // here (the following is just an example):

        // http.rememberMe().alwaysRemember(false);

        // Configure your static resources with public access before calling
        // super.configure(HttpSecurity) as it adds final anyRequest matcher
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/public/**")
            .permitAll();

        super.configure(http); 

        // This is important to register your login view to the
        // view access checker mechanism:
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class); 
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Customize your WebSecurity configuration.
        super.configure(web);
    }

    /**
     * Demo UserDetailsManager which only provides two hardcoded
     * in memory users and their roles.
     * NOTE: This shouldn't be used in real world applications.
     */
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
                User.withUsername("user")
                        .password("{noop}user")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();
        UserDetails admin =
                User.withUsername("admin")
                        .password("{noop}admin")
                        .roles("ADMIN")
                        .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
    }
}
```

I need help. I am stuck here. I dont know how to get (1) username in this class. (2)I dont know how to get the user from the database here. BTW, I do have service, repositry and entity classes working and I can access the Database outsie this class.
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database ?

Comment: You should use your own UserDetailsService or ProviderManager with the AuthenticationManager you need. In you case implement the UserDetailService

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should create UserDetailService and UserPrincipal classes:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

private final UserRepository userRepository;

public MyUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}


@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
    User user = userRepository.findByName(username);
    if(user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }
    return new MyUserPrincipal(user);
}
}

public class MyUserPrincipal implements UserDetails {
private User user;

public MyUserPrincipal(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return Collections.singletonList(new 
SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return this.user.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return this.user.getName();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

And afted it configurate security class like that:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurity {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http, 
PasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder,

UserDetailsService 
userDetailService) throws Exception {
    return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailService)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
            .and()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```